# Scala: illegal inheritance; self-type Y does not conform to X's selftype SELF

Tags: scala, self-type

I have a trait, which takes a type parameter, and I want to say that the objects that implements this trait will also conform to this type parameter (using generics, for Java's compatibility)

The following code:

```
trait HandleOwner[SELF <: HandleOwner[SELF]] {
self : SELF =>
    // ...
    def handle: Handle[SELF]
}

trait Common[SELF <: Common[SELF]]  extends HandleOwner[SELF] {
    // ...
}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
illegal inheritance;  self-type test.Common[SELF] does not conform to
test.HandleOwner[SELF]'s selftype SELF
```

If I change Common to:

```
trait Common[SELF <: Common[SELF]]  extends HandleOwner[SELF] {
self : SELF =>
    // ...
}
```

Then the error goes away.

Why is it that I have to repeat the same declaration in every non-concrete type. If I would have a base class, and say "extends Comparable", I don't have to repeat "extends Comparable" in every derived type, as long as the *concrete classes* implement the compareTo method. I think it should be the same thing here. I am just saying that a type extending HandleOwner *will be* also a SELF, and the compiler should just accept it, and take it into consideration while not requiring every non-concrete subtype to repeat the same thing again.

A am doing this to avoid having to use a class-cast, but I will be literally extending every class from this trait, and I don't see that I should have to repeat this declarations hundreds or even thousands of times!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Self type is more akin to generic constraint than to inheritance. With `class C[A <: B]`, the constraint must be repeated all along in subclasses : `class D[A <: B] extends C[A]`. The constraint must be repeated until it is satisfied, that is until you have chosen an actual parameter type which indeed satisfies `<: B`. Same for the self type. Writing `self: A =>` does not makes your type extend `A`. It ensures that it will ultimately have to be mixed in with  A before it is actually instantiated.

On the opposite, when you extend `Comparable`, you have made your class a `Comparable`, not put a constraint for later on. But the fact that you need to implement `compareTo` has still to be repeated all along with `abstract` until you actually implement it.

Certainly the compiler could do without repeating `<: B`, `self: A =>`, and `abstract`, the info is available to it. This is language designer choice. At least, having to repeat `self: A =>` is not different from the rules everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't make it less tiresome, but at least now it makes sense.